# Rule-based labelling in QGIS - problem moving labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, rule-based

I have just started to use the Rule-based labeling feature in QGIS but am not able to move the labels - x and y coordinates are defined

Comment: Could you perhaps [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/172417/edit) your post to include screenshots of the options you used? How did you define your x and y coordinates, are they stored in the attributes table?

Comment: You could use the easycustomlabeling plugin. You can convert your labels from a certain layer into movable labels.. If you don't have to many labels you could consider using this plugin

Comment: It's not possible to do in QGIS 2.12. You'd need to switch to non rule based labels.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the X and Y coordinates for your label with the rule-based renderer then your label will be fixed at that point.

You could build an expression to alter the X and/or Y coordinate.  For (a somewhat contrived) example:

`case when type = city then $x + 500 else $x end`

Otherwise, the EasyCustomLabelling plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/EasyCustomLabeling/) as mentioned above will give you full control over label placement.  Just be aware that the labels are saved to a memory layer and will not persist.